Grading system by using switch statement
i've posted it before. but i want to make it way more concise. and now it is not working. i want to input marks of the students and likewise want to get the grade afterwhile. but it is not totally working . value that i ever input here are showing off just "F". that's so annoying. Would you please help me with my shortcomings in this code that will make it more accepting to others.
#include<stdio.h>
int main()

{
    int num;
    printf("Enter any number : ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    switch(num)
    {
    case 1:
    {
       if(num>100 || num<0)
       {
         printf("Invalid number");
       }
         break;
       }

    case 2:
    {
        if(num>=80 && num<=100)
        {
         printf("A+");
        }

        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        if(num>=70 && num<=79)
      {
        printf("A");
      }
        break;
    }

    case 4:
    {
      if(num>=60 && num<=69)
      {
        printf("A-");
      }

        break;
    }

    case 5:
    {
        if(num>=50 && num<=59)
        {
         printf("B");
        }

        break;
    }


    case 6:
    {
        if(num>=40 && num<=49)
        {
         printf("C");
        }

        break;
    }

    case 7:
    {
        if(num>=32 && num<=39)
        {
          printf("D");
        }

        break;
    }

    default:

           printf("F");
    }
}

